# how to link a margin graphic to a URL

Tags: graphics, hyperref, marginpar

I am trying to create a margin graphic that is linked to a url. 
So when I click it in the pdf document, the url will open in a browser.
I cannot figure out how to do that. 
My try below does not work out.

```
\marginpar{
 \href{http://www.arxiv.org}{
 \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{pics/infosymbol_2.jpg}}
}
```

Any ideas? Thank in advance! 
Mark

PS: An error occurred. For some reason it now works out. So this post may be considered obsolete and can be deleted, I guess.

Comment: What does *does not work out* mean? Do you get some error message, does the icon appear without the link? Or something else?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.